# Bootstrap. Как сделать сложный li элемент

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, списки

Хочу сделать список ссылок, чтобы в некоторых строчках списка была одна или несколько ссылок.

Допустим у меня есть ссылка1 без ссылки на гитхаб, а вторая строка списка имеет ссылку на скачивание плюс ссылку на исходники на гитхабе. И чтобы у обеих ссылок ширина блока одинаковая была

Как мне сделать класс `github` чтобы я мог легко добавлять его к другим ссылкам.

Пробовал вот так:

HTML:

```
<ul class="example_view">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <a href="foo.rar">Foo binary link</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 github">
                <a href="my_github_link.html">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.github {
    background: url('../images/github.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 3% 3% 3% auto;
}

.example_view li {
    padding: 3% 2%;
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    background: #ddbdff;
    font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Но высота гихабовского `col`'а становится равной `0.989583px`

Может есть способ проще и изысканней? Хардкод не нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, способ лаконичнее - есть. Ссылку-иконку, если она есть - добавляем в `li > .pull-right > a`, а основную ссылку располагаем традиционно в `li > a`.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="my_github_link.html" class="icon icon-github"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="foo.rar">Foo binary link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Я использовал бутстраповский класс `.list-unstyled` для генерации списка без маркеров и паддинга слева. И стилизовал `li` элементы этого списка, как было у вас с `.example_view li`:

```
.list-unstyled > li {
  background: #ddbdff;
  font-size: 2vmin;
  line-height: 4vmin;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  padding: 3% 2%;
}
```

> `.pull-right` - тоже класс бутстрапа, он применяет к блоку атрибут `float: right`, в итоге блок располагается в крайней правой части контейнера, в нашем случае - в крайней правой части `li`. А основная ссылка будет занимать всю доступную ей ширину, слишком длинная ссылка перенесется на следующую строку:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылок-иконок внутри блока `.pull-right` вы можете разместить сколько угодно - они будут располагаться в крайней правой части `li` в один ряд с небольшим отступом друг от друга.

```
  <li>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="my_github_link.html" class="icon icon-github"></a>
      <a href="my_github_link.html" class="icon icon-gitlab"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="foo.rar">Foo binary link</a>
  </li>
```

За отступы между иконками отвечают стили:

```
.icon + .icon {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

В примере выше также видно разные классы у ссылок иконок - `.icon-github` и `.icon-gitlab`. Меняя эти классы у ссылок-иконок - вы можете использовать разные изображения. Единственное условие - изображения должны быть квадратными, чтобы не было нарушения пропорций. Если ваша иконка прямоугольная - просто впишите ее в квадратный холст и сохраните в таком виде.

За это отвечают эти стили:

```
.icon {
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4vmin;
  width: 4vmin;
}
.icon-github {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg');
}
.icon-gitlab {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/GitLab_Logo.svg');
}
```

Обратите внимание на высоту и ширину иконок - они равны интерлиньяжу основной ссылки (`4vmin`). Это помогает выровнять ссылки-иконки по высоте вместе с текстом (хотя это и не единственный способ добиться этого).

Также `background-size: contain` здесь можно уже не использовать, подойдет и `cover`.

Если что нужно поправить - отпишите в комментарии. Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/Lnr4a4wp/

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно растянуть ссылку по оставшейся ширине и высоте без `col-*`? И можно ли добавить к гитхабу другие кнопки на другие сервисы, чтобы они также рядом стояли и соответственно длина ссылки бинарной меньше была

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Да, можно добавлять другие кнопки, без ограничений. А бинарная ссылка будет занимать всю оставшуюся ширину `li`